# Pseudo inverse: What is the best way to solve F from $FA^kB$ and $FA^kG$ if $A, B, G$ are known?

Tags: matrices, inverse, optimal-control, pseudoinverse

Assume that we know $A, B, G$ and also we know $y^{(1)}_k = FA^kG$ and $y^{(2)}_k = FA^kB$. But I don't know $F$. I want to find $F$.

I want to take adventages of both $y^{(1)}_k$ and $y^{(2)}_k$, and that's the question. How can I find $F$ if I need to take adventage to $y^{(1)}_k$ and $y^{(2)}_k$? They are measurement data by the way of a impulse response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse inverse**:

$$
P^+ \;\; =\;\; P^T\left (PP^T\right )^{-1}.
$$

In particular, you should solve for

$$
F \;\; =\;\; y_k^{(1)}\left (A^kG\right )^+ \hspace{2pc}\text{and}\hspace{2pc} F \;\; =\;\; y_k^{(2)}\left (A^kB\right )^+.
$$

In terms of "blending" your measurements together to get one answer for $F$, I can see two options:

**Averaging**

If $y_k^{(1)}$ and $y_k^{(2)}$ were the same size, then you can blend your solution together by adding both equations together:

$$
y_k^{(1)} + y_k^{(2)} \;\; =\;\; FA^k(G+B)
$$

in which case you solve

$$
F \;\; =\;\; \left (y_k^{(1)} + y_k^{(2)}\right )\left [A^k(B+G)\right ]^+.
$$

**Concatenation**

If your vectors are not the same size, then what you can do instead is concatenate them to obtain

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{c}
y_k^{(1)} \\
y_k^{(2)} \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
FA^kG \\
FA^kB \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; \doteq \;\; \widetilde{F}\left [ \begin{array}{c}
A^kG \\
A^kB \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

then you can solve for the larger concatenated $\widetilde{F}$ matrix as

$$
\widetilde{F} \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
y_k^{(1)} \\
y_k^{(2)} \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
\left (A^kG\right )^+ & 0 \\
0 & \left (A^kB\right )^+ \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

Comment: Thank you. I know that answer! But If I want to use them together?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Take a look at my edits.